# Why does it say I have the wrong number of arguments with RestClient Delete Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rest-client

I have been using RestClient to call the API, so here I am calling the DELETE method to delete one image:

```
@mposter_D = params[:mposter_D]
@mid_D = params[:mid_D]
req = Hash.new
req['mov'] = @mid_D

puts "....#{req.to_json}"
resource_pos = RestClient::Resource.new
Rails.application.config.sta_url+"/movi/pos/"+@mposter_D 
response_pos = resource_pos.delete req.to_json, :content_type => :json
```

After calling this I am getting this:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)): in the last line of code
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  Apparently you cannot pass parameters from within the url when doing a delete method.  (i.e. This will NOT work: http://example.com/resource?foo=bar&baz=qux)

If you need to add parameters to your delete request use the following format:

`RestClient.delete 'http://example.com/resource', :params => {:foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux'}`

[See the restclient docs section called Query Parameters](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#query-parameters)

Comment: Where did you find that you can only pass a single url in a delete request? I would also like to pass authorization details `{:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}` and can't figure out if it's possible. Call would look like: `RestClient.delete "http://example.api.com/users/sign_out", {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}, :params => {:api_token => api_token, :user_id => user_id}`

Comment: From the restclient docs they did it like this: # DELETE request with modified headers: 
`RestClient.delete 'http://example.com/resource', {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g'}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, to use both authorization header and params, the :params key is actually pulled out of the headers hash. `RestClient.get 'http://example.com/resource', {:Authorization => 'Bearer cT0febFoD5lxAlNAXHo6g', :params => {:foo => 'bar', :baz => 'qux'}}`.  https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/397#issuecomment-110527709

Answer (score 0):

All I know about delete via rest_client is that, it takes only one parameter :

```
RestClient.delete 'http://demo.com/your_resourse'
```

you have to pass your url in that method. Thanks

Comment: So how can i pass that json with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RestClient.delete 'http://foo.com/your_resourse_id?#{req.to_query}'
```

Or:

```
RestClient.delete 'http://foo.com/your_resourse_id?mov=' + @mid_D
```

Comment: here how can i pass the json and header value with this?

Comment: Try : RestClient.delete 'http://foo.com/your_resourse_id?#{req.to_query}', :content_type => :json, :accept => :json

Comment: Or this : http://rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.1/RestClient#delete-class_method

Comment: RestClient.delete("http://foo.com/#{@mposter_D}?#{req.to_query}",:user => session[:user_name],:password => session[:password], :content_type => :json){
 |response|

     puts "....#{response.code}"

}
got the response 500
here the problem is, cloud only take the url like "http://foo.com/#{@id}" and give that json in body, I have tested that in restclinet console. so  if i am giving like http://foo.com/#{@mposter_D}?#{req.to_query}, how the cloud method read that?